# Use Promise or callbacks in this use-case?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this use-case where I am not sure if it's better to use a Promise or not.
The problem I see, is that I have a 3-case scenario:

- success
- failure
- abort(nothing happens)

My code-sample is here:

```js
class MyView{

// ...

    /**
     * Saves the record changes. Process the uploads. 
     * If beforeSave returns true, nothing should happen.
     * If the view has uploads, process them before saving the record.
     *
     * @param {Callback|Function} success
     * @param {Callback|Function} failure
     */
    saveRecord: function (success, failure) {
        const me = this,
            view = me.getView();

        if (false === view.fireEvent('beforeSave')) {
            //this is the abort scenario
            return;
        }

        if (view.hasUploads()) {
            view.processUploads(() => {
                me.executeRecordSave(success, failure);
            });
        } else {
            me.executeRecordSave(success, failure);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Save the Record Effectively
     * @private
     * @param {Callback|Function} success
     * @param {Callback|Function} failure
     */
    executeRecordSave: function (success, failure) {
        const me = this,
            view = me.getView();

        const record = me.vmGet('record');

        RecordSaver.saveRecord(record, view, {
            success: success,
            failure: failure
        });
    },

// ...

}
```

The current usage is:

```js
const view = new MyView();

view.saveRecord(() => {
    console.log('success');
}, () => {
    console.log('success');
});
```

and I would like to replace it with a Promise:

```js
const view = new MyView();

// would like to replace it with a Promise:
view.saveRecord().then(() => {
    console.log('success');
}, () => {
    console.log('success');
});
```

but in case of "abort" this Promise will never be fulfilled.

The only problem I see with the promise is this piece of code which will never fulfill the promise.

```js
        if (false === view.fireEvent('beforeSave')) {
            return;
        }
```

so I am not sure if I actually use a Promise in this case.

Or, other way, I could return a Promise which will NEVER be fulfilled in case of "abort". Is that ok?

Comment: Does  `RecordSaver.saveRecord()` return a promise ?

Comment: How does your logic differ after abort vs after successful record save? I mean, couldn't abort be considered as *resolved* Promise? From what I understand, *abort* is not an error, it's just *doing nothing but it's ok*. In such a case resolving a Promise with an `abort = true` parameter would make sense. Then in `.then()` you would do something like `if (abort) return;`. However, it adds another `if` and therefore complicates the code. I don't know the whole context but from what you've described converting to Promises won't make any improvement - just a different approach.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek abort is NOT an error, but it's also not a "success". For example, if the record is saved(success) then one would like to close the view or do some other actions. In case of abort, none of that should be done (this is why in the current code success is not being called in that case). So, practically now, I couldn't call abort as "resolved" without adding additional logic in there.

Comment: @localdev currently not, but that could definitely return a Promise.

Comment: "promises or callbacks" is not a use-case question. It's an architectural and a preference question. Both styles can *do* the exact same things. If your application already uses promises, or if you prefer promise semantics, use promises. If not, use callbacks. There is no objective answer to the question as asked. (If your question is *"How do I express success/failure/abort with promise semantics?"*, that's a different - and better - question altogether.)

Comment: *"return a Promise which will NEVER be fulfilled in case of "abort". Is that ok?"* - Promises are a callback registration facility. A convenient one, but still just that. A promise that you never fulfill is a callback you never call. There is nothing "not ok" with that. If there is nothing to do, do nothing. If there is something to do, like inform the client downstream that you have aborted so it can display that status somewhere... well, then you'd have to come up with a way of transporting that information with promises and callback alike.

Comment: In that same sense - events are a callback registration facility. A convenient one, but still just that. A promise that you never fulfill is an event that you never create. Nothing wrong with it. Whether it's good API behavior depends again on your personal preferences, and the circumstances. Assume you're an HTTP request API that returns promises. When you send a request with the timeout set to "infinity", would you say it's ok to never fulfill the associated promise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both `view.processUploads` and `RecordSaver.saveRecord` return a promise (technically they should)

```
class MyView{

    // ...

    /**
     * Saves the record changes. Process the uploads. 
     * If beforeSave returns true, nothing should happen.
     * If the view has uploads, process them before saving the record.
     *
     * @param {Callback|Function} success
     * @param {Callback|Function} failure
     */
    saveRecord: async () => {
        // use arrow function so you don't need the "me = this"
        const view = this.getView();

        if (false === view.fireEvent('beforeSave')) {
            //this is the abort scenario
            return;
        }

        if (view.hasUploads())
            // Wait for the upload to end
            // the result of the upload should be 
            // saved in a private variable
            // to be used by _executeRecordSave()
            await view.processUploads();
        
        return this._executeRecordSave();
        
    },

    /**
     * Save the Record Effectively
     * @private
     */
    _executeRecordSave: () => {
        const view = this.getView();

        const record = this.vmGet('record');
        // return the saveRecord result as a Promise
        return RecordSaver.saveRecord(record, view);
    },

    // ...

}
```

Usage :

```
const view = new MyView();

view.saveRecord().then(result => {
    if(result === 'success') () => console.log('success') // success function
    if(result === 'failure') () => console.log('failure') // failure function
    if(!result) () => console.log('abort') // abort function
});
```

Also you need to add proper error handler for the upload errors.

Ps: Can't test this code, it should work, sorry in advance if there is any error.